# apache restrict directory based on unix group

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, groups

I have an apache server hosting a website with three main directories. Currently two of the directories are restricted to a subset of users with a group file. But for the third directory, I need to allow all users in the Unix group "students" access to it. As this is a large group 100's of users, and new users are added often, I don't think it is feasible to manually enter all user names in the group file.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want either [mod_auth_pam](http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/) or [mod_auth_external](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) to allow you to use the underlying host system's username/password/group databases.
It's also possible that [mod_authnz_unixgroup](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/wiki/ModAuthzUnixGroup) will suit your needs.

Alternatively if your underlying authentication scheme is LDAP based you could use one of the many LDAP authentication modules for Apache.

> Selection and configuration of the appropriate module is left as an exercise for the reader. We don't have enough information about your environment to determine which module(s) would work best for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed making of an answer, I have been really busy with other work projects.